# $a\cdot(b^{-1}\bmod m)$ Can be be solved using modular multiplication

Tags: modular-arithmetic, multiplicative-function

Does $a\cdot(b^{-1}\bmod m) = (a\bmod m) \cdot(b^{-1}\bmod m).$

where $\bmod$ represents remainder left on division with $m$.

$b^{-1} \bmod m$ is multiplicative inverse.

Comment: Please check that if my edit still preserve your meaning.

Comment: Its actually a * (multiplicative inverse of b with m)

Comment: @user253387 If so, then for $a>m$, the both sides are clearly different.

Comment: After the multipication on the right hand side, do you take again the modulo $m$?

Comment: @user253387 or was your original "$=$" sign supposed to be a "$\equiv$" sign?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you consider both sides modulo $m$.
Then the answer is yes.
More generaly, let $a=qm+r$ and $b=km+c$, then 
$$a\cdot b=(qm+r)(km+c)=m(qkm+cq+kr)+rc.$$
Hence 
$$ab \equiv rc \hspace{0.2 cm}(mod \hspace{0.2 cm} m).$$
On the other hand,
$a\equiv r \hspace{0.2 cm}(mod\hspace{0.2 cm} m)$ and $b \equiv c\hspace{0.2 cm} (mod\hspace{0.2 cm} m)$. Therefore
$$(a\equiv (mod \hspace{0.2 cm}m))\cdot (b \equiv (mod\hspace{0.2 cm} m))\equiv r c \hspace{0.2 cm}(\hspace{0.2 cm}mod m).$$